# SQL Help (For Each)

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write an SQL Statement that needs to loop through a list of departments, kind of like a For Each.

Heres what I have so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT AVG(salary),assigned->name
FROM edu_ucla_cs241_termproj_schema.InstructorImpl
WHERE assigned->name = 'Anthropology'
```

This will give me a table of
    Avg Salary  Department
    90.15   Anthropology

However, I want to loop through each department. Can I make this query take a variable and loop through each department name?

Comment: You do not loop in SQL. Looping is a procedural concept, but SQL is declarative.

Comment: @Tom: You can loop through cursor results, among other things.  It's not recommended practice, but it is available.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Ponies. Personally, I have never used cursors as I have always had a real procedural language at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not use

```
SELECT  AVG(salary),
        assigned->name
FROM edu_ucla_cs241_termproj_schema.InstructorImpl
GROUP BY assigned->name
```

Comment: Thanks! The group by totally helped.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  assigned->name, AVG(salary)
FROM edu_ucla_cs241_termproj_schema.InstructorImpl
GROUP BY assigned->name
```

You can also get a bit more info as in

```
SELECT  assigned->name, COUNT(*) AS NbEmployees, AVG(salary) AS AvSalary, 
        MIN(salary) AS MinSalary, MAX(salary) AS MaxSalary
FROM edu_ucla_cs241_termproj_schema.InstructorImpl
GROUP BY assigned->name
```

Your request/suggestion for a "*variable* [to *loop* through departments]" indicates your **thinking in terms of procedural (imperative) programming languages**.  While SQL, or SQL extensions support this programing paradigm, you'll find that **SQL is a lot more powerful when used in a declarative fashion** (as with the queries above: you "declare" what you want, and let SQL worry about doing the "looping" and other steps necessary to fulfill the request)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average salary for all records AND a listing of the name column for each record, you need to use 2 separate queries

Answer (score 0):

Looping through query results is done in most databases through the use of cursors inside a stored procedure.  Without knowing the specifics of the question and the database in use, it's tough to advise how you might implement what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get the avg salary for all  `assigned->name` [ i hope this is department name ], then try the solution given by astander

```
SELECT assigned->name,AVG(salary)
FROM edu_ucla_cs241_termproj_schema.InstructorImpl    
GROUP BY assigned->name
```

otherwise, if you wantlto get the avg salary for certain departments then you will have to create the query dynamically, like this:

```
SELECT assigned->name,AVG(salary)
FROM edu_ucla_cs241_termproj_schema.InstructorImpl
WHERE assigned->name in ( 'name1', 'name2' ... )
GROUP BY assigned->name
```